# Sum of all the values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I have a warehouses dictionary (shown below) and I need to get the sum of 'tons'. The values can be at various depths in the dictionary.

```
warehouses = { 
    "Warehouse Lisboa": [
        { "name": "apples", "tons": 4},
        { "name": "oranges", "tons": 10},
        { "name": "lemons", "tons": 50}
    ], 
    "Warehouse Cascais": { 
            "Branch 1": [
                { "name": "apples", "tons": 10},
                { "name": "oranges", "tons": 24}
            ],
            "Branch 2": [
                { "name": "apples", "tons": 16},
                { "name": "oranges", "tons": 8}
            ]
    }, 
    "Warehouse Oeiras": { 
            
            "Branch 1": { 
                "Sub Branch 1":{
                    "Sub sub Branch 1": [
                        { "name": "lemons", "tons": 10}       
                    ]
                } 
            },
            "Branch 2": [ 
                { "name": "apples", "tons": 3}    
            ]
    }
}
```

I tried the following but it returned -  *TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'*:

```
def stock_fruits(warehouses):
    return sum(warehouses.values())
```

How do I get the sum of all the 'tons' values in the dictionary?

Comment: You have more than just a list of dictionaries as your question title states. I suggest creating a simpler example that is just a list of dictionaries to solve first.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) approach:

```
from typing import Union

def stock_fruits(curr: Union[dict, list]) -> int:
    if isinstance(curr, dict):
        return sum(stock_fruits(value) for value in curr.values())
    return sum(entry["tons"] for entry in curr)

warehouses = {
    "Warehouse Lisboa": [
        {"name": "apples", "tons": 4},
        {"name": "oranges", "tons": 10},
        {"name": "lemons", "tons": 50}
    ],
    "Warehouse Cascais": {
        "Branch 1": [
            {"name": "apples", "tons": 10},
            {"name": "oranges", "tons": 24}
        ],
        "Branch 2": [
            {"name": "apples", "tons": 16},
            {"name": "oranges", "tons": 8}
        ]
    },
    "Warehouse Oeiras": {
        "Branch 1": {
            "Sub Branch 1": {
                "Sub sub Branch 1": [
                    {"name": "lemons", "tons": 10}
                ]
            }
        },
        "Branch 2": [
            {"name": "apples", "tons": 3}
        ]
    }
}
print(f"{stock_fruits(warehouses) = }")
```

**Output:**

```
stock_fruits(warehouses) = 135
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to compute the sum:

```
    def stock_fruits(warehouses):
        fruit_sum = 0

        queue = deque(list(warehouses.values()))
        while queue:
            node = queue.popleft()
            if isinstance(node, List):
                fruit_sum += sum([item.get('tons', 0) for item in node])
            else:
                queue.extend(list(node.values()))

        return fruit_sum
```